# How to redirect to a post action in a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I am creating a project that uses Stripe API for donations (using user entry custom amount donations).

Basically I have 2 controllers

First one is paymentinfo controller (which has all the functions for the stripe) Basically creating Checkout::Sessions

Second is my frontendviews controller (which is responsible for all the pages of the website)

In my frontendviews controller , I have this method

```
def createpayment

    @paymentinfo = Paymentinfo.new(pay_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @paymentinfo.save
            format.html { redirect_to donation_url, flash: {thanks: 'Thank you for providing us with your desired amount'}}
        else
            format.html { redirect_to donation_url, flash: {msg: 'Minimum Donation is 1 USD'}}
        end
    end
 end
 
 def pay_params
    params.require(:paymentinfo).permit(:amount)
 end
```

Basically I want to redirect_to , to an action in the paymentinfo controller

```
def createcustom
  amount = Paymentinfo.last.amount
  amountfinal = (amount*100);

  @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        name: 'Custom Amount donation',
        description: 'Custom Amount donation',
        amount: amountfinal,
        currency: 'eur',
        quantity: 1
      }],
  success_url: paymentinfo_success_url + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  cancel_url: paymentinfo_cancel_url
  )

respond_to do |format|
  format.js # renders create.js.erb
end
```

end

To redirect to this method (which is a post), I am in search of a quick and easy way to do it. Preferably without creating a new controller (I know its not the ideal way and not very DRY) but is there a way around it? (I know I cant do it with redirect_to.

Comment: You can't. Redirects in HTTP are ALWAYS GET requests. You should really just rethink this and state what the actual goal you want to acheive is - not your proposed solution which is a no-go.

Comment: Well at the end of the day , I want a single button to do 2 different actions , in 2 different controllers but with a specific order.

Comment: You can do that by using promises to send one ajax request after the other one finishes. I would really step off the `js.erb` bandwagon a bit and write some real JS to solve this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Is there any other way to go with it? with my current approach its a bit time crucial , I will check out the reference obviously (even as a temp fix)

Comment: Not do it in two different actions to begin with?

Comment: Yea , I now went with that route , trying to resolve in form_tag the remote: true and should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [gem repost](https://github.com/vergilet/repost). It's very easy to use

Comment: Thank you , will have that in mind , I just added some things to my controller in order to make it work